# What do scriptures say about planet mars?

Tags: scripture

What do scriptures say about planet mars?

Is there any mention about that anywhere in Hinduism context?

Comment: Can you make clear in what context you want to know about Mars? because there are many references in Vedic Astrology as well as puranas about Mangal or Mars or Angaraka

Comment: @PratikBhat This question is not too broad, please rethink.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi this question has been closed. Please edit it if you think otherwise and nominate for reopening. the community will decide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Shiva Purana, Mars is [mangal graha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangala) in Hinduism, son of goddess earth. Lord Mangal (Mars) is one of the nine planets or navagrahas. He is also known by the names Angaraka and Kuja. He is considered the son of Prithvi or Bhumi, the Earth Goddess.He is associated with strength, valor, and courage. Lord Mangal is the protector of dharma (righteousness), and the purpose of life. Mars is owner of Mesh and Vrishik Rashi. This planet is having power that affects a person's life.

> Mangala represents drive and physical energy, self-confidence and ego, strength, anger, impulsiveness, heroism and adventurous nature. Mangala rules over blood, muscles and bone marrow. He is associated with battle, war and soldiers.

If you are constantly changing jobs, you may have Mars planet astrological problem, if you are mangalik, you have late marriage problem. If you have Manglik as on upper half box, you may have aggressive nature and may loose control of your mind sometimes. These are symptoms, Mangal graha problems are also like you may have secret enemies at your workplace.

### Scriptures:

> **Astrology:** Lord Mangal has four hands, and carries a trident and mace as weapons. He wears red ornaments. Worshiping Lord Mangal frees one from skin illnesses, debts, and poverty. The gemstone of Lord Mangal is the red coral, and his day is Tuesday. He is the guardian of the south direction.
>
> **Ramayana :** Many causes are there of planet mars in Hinduism. When ravana caged planets in Ramayana this Graha was also caged.
>
> **Ganeshpuranam:** Once the elder brother of Hiranyaksh had kidnapped Prithvi Devi (Earth). To get Prithvi Devi released from him, God appeared in the form of 'Varah'. The God killed Hiranyaksh and Prithvi Devi was rescued. At that time Prithvi Devi was very pleased with the God and she wished to marry him. At the time of Varahavtar, the glowing of God was like having thousands of suns in the sky. It was unbearable. Then the God appeared in the beautiful and original form to fulfill the wishes of Prithvi Devi. They married and lived alone for one year. Mangal was born to them.
>
> **Shiva Purana- Chap 2.71 :** Once when Lord Shiva was engrossed in 'deep meditation' upon his abode Mount Kailash, three drops of perspiration originated from his forehead and fell down on the earth. From those drops manifested a very beautiful infant, who was of reddish complexion and who had four arms.The child was handed over to the earth goddess, Bhumi for upbringing by Lord Shiva. The child was named Bhaum as he was nurtured and brought up by 'Bhumi' (earth).
>
> When Bhaum grew up, he went to Kashi and did a tremendous penance to please lord Shiva. Lord Shiva blessed him by granting him 'Mangala loka (the Abode of Mangala), which was superior even to the 'Shukra loka' (the Abode of the god of Venus - Shukra). The same 'Bhauma' is established in the solar system by the name of Mangala (the planet Mars).

No other scriptures(I know) states anything about this planet. But there are Vrat kathas related to Lord Mars you can read them [here](http://bharathkidilse.blogspot.in/2009/12/mangalvar-vrat-katha.html).

Comment: If you say "according to Shiva Purana", then you should actually quote the Shiva Purana.  And in any case you should cite better sources than Wikipedia, preferably Hindu scripture (especially when the question is specifically about scripture).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Please give me some time, I will read and find out it from sources, but it may take some time. Is it ok with you?

Comment: Yes, there's no hurry.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Hi keshavji, I have cited sources.. Thank you for having patience... Thank you very much... :)

Comment: Down voter can you please comment?