# What do hindu scriptures say about life on MARS?

Tags: scripture, puranas, navagraha

is there any mention of Life on MARS in any of the hindu texts Shastras or Puranas or Vedas. I know there were some questions around but never specific to life on Mars. I am very curious to know if there is any mention of life ever existed on planet MARS or anything related to Alien beings on MARS.

Comment: I don't think Hindu Scriptures talk about life on Mars. Hindu scriptures talk about 14 Lokas. Satya, Tapo, Jana,Mahar,Suvar,Bhuvar,**Bhu**, Atala,Vitala, Nitala, Rasatala, Mahatala, Sutala and Patala.  Different Scholars interpret Bhuloka differently. Some say Bhuloka is only Planet earth and some say entire Universe. The other lokas are in different planes of consciousness to Bhuloka.

Comment: But Mars is described in Hindu Scriptures. See [What do scriptures say about planet mars?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3229/3500)

Comment: I think all of these lokas are symbolic not the physcial creations

Comment: No. They are real. They may exist in different dimension. Higher consciousness beings can travel all lokas. But man is microcosm. He has brahmanda in him. See http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10322

Comment: thats exactly what I am saying there is no physical chakras or sushamna naadi in the body its more symbolic

Comment: Not symbolic. They exist in Sukshma sareera or Subtle body. See [What are Five Layers (Pancha Kosha) of Human?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3073)

Comment: even if they exist in another dimension they are not physical , they are physical only if they exist in the dimension we are living in and thats how we can see and feel them, matter of fact even if its in subtle body its not physical wiki says "A subtle body is one of a series of psycho-spiritual constituents of living beings, according to various esoteric, occult, and mystical teachings."

Comment: Don't refer wiki. They write articles from their view. Brahman is beyond everything. How can we know or understand him if we consider only physical aspects? Subtle things are not symbolic.

Comment: Scriptures don't evolve. But they are timeless.

Answer (score 1):

Rishi भारद्वाज (Bhardwaj) asked कुंभकर्ण (great scientist of his time who used to meditate for 6 months and 6 months in his laboratory) that how long does it take your spaceship to go to moon, He answered 1 day.

भारद्वाज (Bhardwaj) said go to mars and tell me what is the status of life there.

कुंभकर्ण came back and tell him that **life is there but in another dimension, which we can not see through naked eyes**, in fact they said no planet is left alone with out life.

Which **off course no one can believe**, but again 99% is Dark energy and dark matter, which no one knows about.

We already have many evidence that science in that time was much more vast in terms of quantum Physics, **Hanuman had an anklet which uses sun rays and generate enough power to made him fly**.

Source: Book "रावण ईतिहास" by "(श्रृंगी ऋषि in Satyug) & कृष्ण दत्त in present life"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54113/discussion-on-answer-by-rishi-what-do-hindu-scriptures-say-about-life-on-mars).